# using cumsum method on multi level index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, cumsum

I have the following multi-level dataframe (partial)

```
                    Px_last FINAL   RETURN  Stock_RES   WANTED 
Stock   Date                    
ALKM    10/27/2016  0.0013    1     -53.85    NaN       -53.85
         1/17/2017  0.0009    1      111.11   NaN        57.26
         1/18/2017  0.0012    1      233.33   NaN       290.60
         1/23/2018  0.0012    1       16.67   NaN       307.26
         1/30/2018  0.0019    1      -42.11   NaN       265.16
ANDI     12/28/2017 0.0017    1      370.59   NaN       370.59
         2/14/2018  0.0324    1      20.00    NaN       390.59
APPZ     9/22/2017  0.0002    1     -50.00    NaN       -50.00
         12/5/2017  0.0001    1    -100.00    NaN      -150.00
         12/6/2017  0.0001    1       0.00    NaN      -150.00
```

I can do a cumulative sum for the entire dataframe with the following code

```
df3['TTL_SUM'] = df3['RETURN'].cumsum()
```

But want I want to do is a cumulative sum by each stock but when I do the following I get  a column of NaN.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?  SEE dataframe above

```
df3['Stock_RES'] = df3.groupby(level=0)['RETURN'].sum()
```

It does seem to work when I assign that to a variable but ultimately I want to get it in the dataframe

```
RESULTS = df3.groupby(level=0)['RETURN'].sum()
```

Can someone help me out.  Seems like the same code to me so not sure why it won't add directly into a dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were using `sum` and not `cumsum` in a `groupby` context.

```
df.assign(WANTED1=df.groupby('Stock').RETURN.cumsum())

                  Px_last  FINAL  RETURN  Stock_RES  WANTED  WANTED1
Stock Date                                                          
ALKM  10/27/2016   0.0013      1  -53.85        NaN  -53.85   -53.85
      1/17/2017    0.0009      1  111.11        NaN   57.26    57.26
      1/18/2017    0.0012      1  233.33        NaN  290.60   290.59
      1/23/2018    0.0012      1   16.67        NaN  307.26   307.26
      1/30/2018    0.0019      1  -42.11        NaN  265.16   265.15
ANDI  12/28/2017   0.0017      1  370.59        NaN  370.59   370.59
      2/14/2018    0.0324      1   20.00        NaN  390.59   390.59
APPZ  9/22/2017    0.0002      1  -50.00        NaN  -50.00   -50.00
      12/5/2017    0.0001      1 -100.00        NaN -150.00  -150.00
      12/6/2017    0.0001      1    0.00        NaN -150.00  -150.00
```